# realme X50 5G - Restarting Each Night At ~3:00 AM

Tags: tethering, usb-tethering, realme

I'm currently using a realme X50 5G (European Edition) to tether my internet.

I've come across an annoying issue where each night at around 3:00 AM the phone seems to restart or do something that means USB tethering gets disabled.

The phone won't automatically USB tether, even with the developer settings set to do USB tethering by default.

I've also tried using Automate to both automatically tether when USB is connected (which works) and also to try and turn tethering on at 3:10 AM. That last one doesn't seem to work, I feel like the phone needs unlocking (even though I disabled the lock) before it works. Automate is allowed to start up and run in the background etc.

Yes, I've checked that auto restarting isn't enabled etc.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

So this isn't really a fix, but it's a work-around that seems to stop the device from restarting in the early morning.

I'm using the "[Automate](https://llamalab.com/automate/)" app to keep the CPU and screen alive. There are community flows that do just this if you search, or you can easily make it yourself.

What I don't know that I'll test tonight is if I can let the screen turn off, but keep the CPU awake. I'll report back how that goes as I'd rather not keep the screen on, even if it's super dim.